# what the best tune for generate code in python to mariadb?

Tags: python, mariadb

i have this code for generate unique code,

```
import mysql.connector as mariadb
import time 
import random

mariadb_connection = mariadb.connect(user='XX', password='XX', database='XX', port='3306', host='192.168.XX.XX')
cursor = mariadb_connection.cursor()

FullChar = 'CDHKPMQRVXY123456789'
total = 20
count = 7
entries = []
uq_id = 0
flg_id = None
get_id = None
bcd = None

def inputDatabase(data):
    try:
        maria_insert_query = "INSERT INTO BB_UNIQUE_CODE(unique_code, flag_code, get_id, barcode) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"
        cursor.executemany(maria_insert_query, data)
        mariadb_connection.commit()
        print("Commiting " + str(total) +  " entries..")
    except Exception:
        maria_alter_query = "ALTER TABLE PromoBigrolls.BB_UNIQUE_CODE AUTO_INCREMENT=0"
        mariadb_connection.rollback()
        print("UniqueCode Rollbacked")
        cursor.execute(maria_alter_query)
        print("UniqueCode Increment Altered")
while (0 < 1) :
    for i in range(total):
        
        unique_code = ''.join(random.sample(FullChar, count)) 
        
        entry = (unique_code, flg_id, get_id, bcd)
        entries.append(entry)
    

    inputDatabase(entries)
    #print(entries)
    entries.clear()
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

my code output:

```
1 K4C1D9M null null null
2 K2R9XH3 null null null
3 5M3V9R2 null null null
```

This code is run correctly, but after generated unique code reach 30 M, there is too much rollback, because if there is a same unique code in database it'll rollback the newest data. Any suggestion?
Thanks

Comment: Have you looked into UUID to generate a unique value? https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html

Comment: can i custom the unique code from this?

Comment: yes, you can generate unique values using UUID. It would be a better approach. Any reason to not use an auto-generated value from mariadb?

Comment: Okay i'll try, but how about the rollback in mariadb? should i replace for a better options?

Comment: There may be multiple ways to do it. I don't see a need for rollback. You can create a Unique Constraint on the column in the DB. If the UUID generate is a duplicate (very unlikely) the DB will throw an error. In such a case generate a new UUID and insert again.

Comment: Avoid using `except Exception` instead catch the specific exception your DB driver throws when you breach the Unique Constraint

Comment: Duplicates should be rare; I would just add entires to a set until the set has the number of codes you need. I'd be surprised if you needed to generate more than `2x` random codes to get `x` unique codes.

Comment: Do you need to generate unique codes between runs of the program, or are you only populating the database in a single run? You can do something like iterating over the 20-bit integers in Gray-code order, then treating the bits as subsets of `{1,...,20}` to select characters from a shuffled version of `FullChar`. This should be sufficiently "random", and guarantees that you won't pick a duplicate code without having to remember the previously generated codes.

Comment: oh okay, i see, I changed the schema when inserting unique_code into the database, removed the rollback @shoaib30 and tried to generate unique_code in another way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion UUID is definitely the way to go. By the way your usage of `random.sample()` is rather unusual - you may end up generating the same "unique" code twice (or more) in a row.

I don't know why you would like to customize an UUID, since it is intended to be a *meaningless* unique identifier; but if you really need your ID to be a string made of the chars in `FullChar` then you can generate the UUID, convert it to a list of indexes, and use it to build you final string:

```
def int2code(n, codestring):
    base = len(codestring)
    numbers = []
    while n > 0:
        x = n % base
        numbers.append(x)
        n //= base
    chars = [codestring[c] for c in reversed(numbers)]
    return ''.join(chars)

unique_code = int2code(int(str(uuid.uuid1().int)), FullChar)
```

**EDIT**

As it has been noted by @shoaib30 you were generating 7-chars long codes.

While this is not difficult to handle (the easiest although probably not the smartest way would be to just calculate `uuid.uuid1().int % 20**7` and use it in the function above), it can easily bring to collisions: the UUID is a 128 bit integer, or about 3.4+e38 possible values, while the permutations of 7 out of 20 items are just 3.9+e08, or 390 millions. So you have 1.0e+30 different UUIDs which will be translated to the same code.

Comment: This is a novel solution to generate UID from the FullChar list. The OP is limiting the length of UID to 7 which will generate limited unique values with a set of 20 characters, would be helpful to add to the answer